# Blackberry 10 - Display custom component in ApplicationB which is created in ApplicationA

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I would like to create an application which shows a custom component in ApplicationB which is created in ApplicationA (like we maintain UI projects in C#.NET). It's like allowing the ApplicationB to consume the generic component screen from ApplicationA and modify its contents before rendering the screen (say Title for instance). I could create custom components but was unable to reference it to new project for use, and also wonder how to handle click events for the controls created in custom component for which they should have implemented some event subscription mechanism.

I am using the below URL to create custom components:
https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/ui/custom_components/custom_components_tutorial.html

But the above tutorial doesnt show how to bind events from parent to custom component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to what you describe in Cascades are [Cards](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/invocation/cards.html). However it doesn't sound like this is what you want. If you can implement your UI elements entirely in QML, and place them in a shared directory ApplicationB could import the elements and use them. If you implement in C++ you could create a library (either static or dynamic) and link ApplicationB to the library.